# HashMap Issuses

Tags: java, hashmap

**Edited the getTypeString method in the Flowers class now I just get the pointer to the object**

I'm working on a project for one of my classes. I haven't worked with `HashMap` before and I need to use one. In this java class I'm trying to print out the full description that I have set. But it wont print the `HashMap` value from the key. I have tried to use some code from my book, but with no luck.

This is the class that is calling the class that has the `HashMap`:

```
    public class Garden
    {
        private Gardener gardener;
        private Tools tools;
        private Flowers flowers;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Garden
         */
        public Garden()
        {
           gardener = new Gardener();
           tools = new Tools();

           Flowers rose;
           rose = new Flowers("a beautiful red flower");

           rose.setFlower("red", rose);

           System.out.println(rose.fullDescription());

        }
    }
```

**Edited the getTypeString method**

This is the class that is using the `HashMap`:

```
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Flowers
    {
        private String fDescription;
        private HashMap<String, Flowers> flowers;


        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Flowers
         */
        public Flowers(String fDescription)
        {
          this.fDescription = fDescription;
          flowers = new HashMap<String, Flowers>();
        }

        public void setFlower(String color, Flowers type)
        {
            flowers.put(color, type);
        }

        public String flowerDescription()
        {
            return fDescription;
        }

        public String fullDescription()
        {
            return "The "+ getTypeString() + " is " + fDescription;
        }

        private String getTypeString()
        {
            String des = "";
            Collection<Flowers> vals = flowers.values();
            for(Flowers f : vals){
            des += f;
            }
            return des;
        }
    }
```

The problem, I think, is in the `getTypeString()` function. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

I removed the getTypeString method and edited the fullDescription method:

```
    public String fullDescription()
    {
        return "The "+ type + " is " + fDescription;
    }
```

now I'm trying to get the 'HashMap' to print the objects like so:

"Flower [type= type, description= Description "]"

using thes methods:

```
    public static void printHashMap()
        {
            System.out.println("hashmap: " + flowers);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Flower [type=" + type + ", description=" + fDescription ]";
        }
```

Comment: `flowers.keySet()` returns a `Set<String>`. Maybe you're looking for `flowers.values()`?

Comment: Also, `rose.setFlower("red", rose);` will cause a stack overflow when you try printing the values of `flowers`.

Comment: I would revisit your design.  Consider having a `Single` `Flower` and then if necessary a class that holds a `Collection` of `Flower`.  As your `HashMap` is not static and is inside your `Single` `Flower` object, then everytime that you instantiate a new `Flowers` you will get a new `Map`

Comment: I did forget to make the map static. I have to make it so the garden class makes many instances of the flowers class. HashMap was the only way I can think of to use a key structure, and Im required to use one anyway. @shmosel I tried flowers.values() and I got an error.

Comment: "I got an error" isn't a great problem description. You realize `values()` doesn't return a Set, right?

Comment: I was starting to realize that. How can I get this to do what I need it do.

Comment: @shmosel please look at the edit i made

Comment: @ScaryWombat please look at the edit i made

Answer (score 0):

From your post, what I have understood is that you want to print the description of flowers. So I think you can try something like:

```
private String getTypeString(){
String des = "";
Collection<String> vals = flowers.values();
for(String f : vals){
      des = des + f.flowerDescription();
}
return des;
}
```

Comment: That is exatly what I'm trying to do. However that method was written to convert the object refrence to a string and return it to a method that prints the decription. I edited what you gave me, look above, it prints the pointer.

Comment: Please update your code as: for(Flowers f : vals){ des +=f.flowerDescription(); }

Comment: I didn't need that. I fond a way to do it with out. im trying to get this to work.     '@Override
    public static String toString()
    {
        return "Flower [type=" + type + ", description=" + fDescription + "]";
    }'

Comment: Yes... That way also you can do it. But I think you will have to do a small change in you toString() method. To print the flower type, you will have to do like: flowers.keySet().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]",""). This will return the value as rose. Along which you can concatenate fDescription.

Answer (score -1):

Override the toString method in your class

Declare a toString method with the following modifiers and return type:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.fDescription;
}
```

Implement the method so that it returns a string.

Comment: Be sure you identify and understand ALL the flaws in the OP's code before posting an answer.